# SwiftUI - How to draw on top of image then save drawing and image together as one

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an app that takes a snapshot of a view, then the snapshot is used as a image that the user is able to draw on top of. I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/make-drawing-app-on-ios-wrapped-in-swiftui-db17b29d907d) to get the drawing functionality.

Everything works great however if I try to take a snapshot of the image with the drawing on top it saves it to the photo album as just the image (no drawing). What I want is to use a button to save a snapshot of the image with the newly added drawing. As seen in the code, I've tried using a ZStack in the view I am snapshotting, however, it did not work out for me.

I think I need to update something in the updateUIView but I am not sure what. The minimal reproducible example below will build with the problem. I appreciate any ideas.

Thank you!

Content View

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var snapshotImage: UIImage? = nil
    
    var imageView: some View {
        Image("Test")
        //EmptyView() <- Uncomment and comment out the line above to just use an empty View as an image
    }

    var imageDrawingView: some View {
        ZStack {
            if let image = snapshotImage {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                CanvasViewWrapper()
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if snapshotImage != nil {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    imageDrawingView
                }
                Button("Save Image") {
                    let imageWithDrawing = imageDrawingView.snapshot()
                    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageWithDrawing, nil, nil, nil) // Save to photos
                }
            }
        } else {
            VStack {
                imageView
                Button("Take ScreenShot") {
                    self.snapshotImage = imageView.snapshot()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
        
        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

CanvasView

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CanvasView: UIView {
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect){
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        paths.forEach { path in
            switch(path.type) {
            case .move:
                context.move(to: path.point)
                break
            case .line:
                context.addLine(to: path.point)
                break
            }
        }
        
        context.setLineWidth(10)
        context.setLineCap(.round)
        context.strokePath()
    }
    
    @Published var paths = [Path]()
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
        paths.append(Path(type: .move, point: point))
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
        paths.append(Path(type: .line, point: point))
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

struct Path {
    let type: PathType
    let point: CGPoint
    
    init(type: PathType, point: CGPoint) {
        self.type = type
        self.point = point
    }
    
    enum PathType {
        case move
        case line
    }
}
```

CanvasViewWrapper

```
import SwiftUI

struct CanvasViewWrapper : UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return CanvasView()
    }
        func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        uiView.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

App

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct StackMinimalApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take Snap of UIImageView or UIView with this extension

```
extension UIView {
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
            return renderer.image { rendererContext in
                layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
            }
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
            self.layer.render(in:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return UIImage(cgImage: image!.cgImage!)
        }
    }
    func asImages() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

**Use**

```
let image = someView.asImage()
```

it will return you the UIView with drawing in the form of image Then Save That image in your library.

**To Save**

```
func saveImage(image: UIImage) -> Bool {
    guard let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) ?? UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else {
        return false
    }
    guard let directory = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) as NSURL else {
        return false
    }
    do {
        try data.write(to: directory.appendingPathComponent("fileName.png")!)
        return true
    } catch {   
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return false
    }
}
```

**use**

```
let success = saveImage(image: UIImage(named: "image.png")!)
```

*Get The Image*

```
func getSavedImage(named: String) -> UIImage? {
    if let dir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) {
        return UIImage(contentsOfFile: URL(fileURLWithPath: dir.absoluteString).appendingPathComponent(named).path)
    }
    return nil
}
```

**use**

```
if let image = getSavedImage(named: "fileName") {
    // do something with image
}
```